# Estimate best vector in one vocabulary based on input from another vocabulary

Tags: machine-learning

I have strings from two sources lets call them two different vocabularies maybe and I have an association defined between vectors of strings in vocab1 to vectors of strings in vocab2.

vector_from_vocab_1 -> vector_from_vocab_2

and I have so many such rows in my input data. The lengths of vectors in either vocab1 or vocab2 in each row are not fixed.

What machine learning algorithm can I use to estimate the vector from vocabulary 2 given a "new" vector from vocabulary 1? The input data type is all strings.

It may sound like natural language translation. But the vocabularies are not related to any spoken language.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to DS-SE!

The problem you described here looks like a sequence to sequence (seq2seq) in DL or text to text problems in NLP. Machine Translation and Summarization are two subclasses of these problems.

Please take a look at [HuggingFace Model Hub](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text2text-generation) for some pretrained DL models that might be relevant to your question.